# beforeSaveEntities validating with extra parameters

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to write some custom validation in `beforeSaveEntities` (or `beforeSaveEntity`) that needs to verify that the currently logged in user is the owner of the field being saved. The problem I'm running into is how to access who the current user is.

I have an authorization attribute assigned to the controller that validates the user token etc and stores the authorized user in `Request.Properties`, however I can't access the `HttpRequestMessage` inside `beforeSaveEntities`. Is there a best practice for passing even just the `userID` of the current user into those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to give your `ContextProvider` subclass a property to hold your user info.  Then in your web controller method, you'd have:

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
    var contextProvider = new MyContextProvider(User currentUser);
    return contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

Then the `BeforeSaveEntities` method in the `ContextProvider` will have access to the User.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time working out how to implement the above answer, so have added the my ContextProvider overload here.

```
public class MyContextProvider : EFContextProvider<MyContext>
{
    //The new local user object
    private System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User;

    public CameraContextProvider(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user) : base()
    {
        this.User = user;
    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) 
    {
        if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
             //whatever validations etc you need!
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use the contents of the 'SaveChanges' method described by Steve in this question. Hope this helps!